How to call a function from a structure obtained from a c++ library on c#
There is a library written in c++, here is its H file.
    //...
    extern "C" DWORD WINAPI GetDllVersion(void);
    extern "C" LPVOID WINAPI CreateInstance(const char \*DeviceName);

    #pragma pack(1)

    struct ILE440
    {
    virtual HANDLE WINAPI GetModuleHandle(void) = 0;
    virtual bool WINAPI OpenLDevice(WORD VirtualSlot) = 0;
    //other methods
    }
    //other structs

I called the CreateInstance, and got its result, but how to call the method that is in this result?
    [DllImport("lusbapi.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateLInstance(StringBuilder sb); 
    //---------------------------------------------  
    var instancePtr = CreateInstance(dn);

how to call:
    var intance = AAA(instancePtr); 
    var bbb = intance.OpenDevice(...);

Thanks in advance, sorry for google translit

I expect you need an interop bridge first,  similar to what is done here: https://github.com/ifelsedeveloper/LCardAPINet/blob/master/LCardAPI/LusbapiBridge/LusbapiE2010.cpp because I don't think that ILE440 struct in that C code can become an interface directly in managed code.

Thank you very much, this is a wrapper over another version of the library from the same manufacturer, so this is as close as possible to what I need. Thank you!!!
